# Windows 8.1 makes one of my displays in grayscale. How can I fix it?

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, grayscale

I just re-install windows 8.1 then I've installed Windows8.1-KB2939087-x64, Windows8.1-KB2975061-x64, Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64, Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 and Google Chrome. At that point everything worked normally except that the monitor identified as #2 in the picture below displayed the full HD (1920x1080) improperly.

To fix that I downloaded the Graphics driver for my APU processor with graphics (AMD Fusion APU A4-5000 Quad-Core with AMD Radeon HD8330 Graphics). That's when the second display went haywire and displayed everything in grayscale (though now 1920x1080 takes the entire screen unlike before)

Here is what I get:
[image: color screen against grayscale screen]
I had to photoshop it to grayscale to show you what it looks like because when I take a snapshot of the desktop (print screen) the picture is in full color.

I've also tried to reset my monitor; nothing changes. Also when I boot to windows 10 the color is back again which means this comes from windows 8.1 somehow.

Comment: If the screen shot is in color, then a color image is being sent to the display. Check your cable connections and consider replacing the video cable to the monitor.

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator like I said when I boot to windows 10 both monitors are in color which means it can't be the cable or the monitor.

Comment: indeed ... I missed that, however we must still say *Windows* is sending a color image. What happens if you switch the video cables of your two displays?

Comment: I can't. One is vga the other hdmi

Comment: Let me guess, the greyscale monitor is the VGA one?

Comment: no, the hdmi one.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me on occasion as well. Check for a grayscale filter being applied.

1. Right click on desktop and choose `Personalize`
2. Click `Themes` on the left bar and then choose 'High Contrast Settings` on the right side.
3. There will be a slider called `apply color filter`. Make sure it is off.
   Reference image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyDfn.png

The same menu can also be accessed from control pane > ease of access.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by uninstalling the latest graphics driver and installing an older driver